# A "permission request/ Dialog Alert" when adding a marker on Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to know or if someone can steer me in the direction on how to, when the user clicks on any location on the google map. A "dialog box or permission requests" pops up indicating to the user "Would you like to place a marker here?" with a checkbox I suppose with "yes" or "no". If the user selects yes the marker would be place in that location, if no, nothing would happen. Is this something that is possible to do? Is there a simple solution to such a problem? Any reference material or ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far, please add some code.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I think my question is pretty self-explanatory and how should I go about doing it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It's Very Simple, Add a click listener to `googlemap` and show `AlertDialog` with `yes or no` as in

```
     googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
     {
         @Override
          public void onMapClick(final LatLng arg0)
          {
              showDialog(arg0);
          }
     });

    public void showDialog(final LatLng geo){
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Confirm")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to add Marker?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                        {
                            // add marker with LatLng geo
                             dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                        {
                            //do nothing
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                ).build().show();
       }
```

Comment: Thank you. My implementation was pretty much similar. However, an error comes up in your implementation "cannot resolve .build() method". Why is that? @rajan-ks